# Unable to add user to a new group as default as the user has its name same as old group

Tags: rhel, group

I am using Red Hat Linux 6.
Have a username 'nrajora' and a group name 'nrajora' as default in the system

I created a new group 'super-group' which has all the required privileges.

Now I am trying to add the 'super-group' to my user 'nrajora'
but not able to.

Following is what I have tried:

```
whoami
```

> nrajora

```
id
```

> uid=1101(nrajora) gid=1101(nrajora) groups=1101(nrajora),1102(default)

```
sudo groupadd super-group
sudo usermod -a -G super-group nrajora
id
```

> uid=1101(nrajora) gid=1101(nrajora) groups=1101(nrajora),1102(default)

Nothing changed after above `usermod -a -G` command.

```
sudo usermod -g super-group nrajora
id
```

> uid=1101(nrajora) gid=1101(nrajora) groups=1101(nrajora),1102(default)

Nothing changed after `usermod -g` either.

Whereas when I specify the group name to `id`, it shows me the groups being added.

```
id nrajora
```

> uid=1101(nrajora) gid=1104(super-group)
>   groups=1104(super-group),1102(default)

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might need to log out and back in in order for `id` to pick up changes to the groups of a user.